# How do i gracefully shutdown an StreamExecutionEnvironment that was started with the execute method

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to shutdown a StreamExecutionEnvironment that is started during one of our junit Integration tests. Once all the items in the stream are processed i want to be able to shutdown this execution environment in a deterministic fashion.

Right now when i call StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute method it never returns from that call.

Answer (score 0):

*[May be I am too late here, but will answer for those people who are looking for an answer or hint]*

Actually what you need to do is gracefully exit from the [`SourceFunction<T>`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/SourceFunction.java).
Then the whole `StreamExecutionEnvironment` will be auto closed. To do that, you may need a special end event to send into your source function.

Write or extend (if you are using pre-defined source function) to check the special incoming event, which will be emitted at the end of your integration tests, and break the loop or unsubscribe from the source. The basic pattern would be shown below.

```
public class TestSource implements SourceFunction<Event> {

    public void run(SourceContext<T> ctx) throws Exception {
        while (hasContent()) {
            Event event = readNextEvent();

            if (isAnEndEvent(event)) {
              break;
            }

            ctx.collect(event);
        }

    }

}
```

Depends on your situation, in junit tests, you should send this special event at the end of each/all test cases.

```
// or @AfterClass
@After   
public void doFinish() {
    // send the special event from a different thread.
}
```

Sometimes you might have to do this from a different thread (basically where you generate test events). Not like above.

It is recommended you having a separate source function implementation for your tests because of this matter, so it is easier to modify to accept a special close event. But *never* in your actual source function which is expecting to go into the production. :)

---

The [javadoc of SourceFunction](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/SourceFunction.java#L95) also explains about a `stop()` function, which you can see an example from how [`TwitterSource`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/8674b69964eae50cad024f2c5caf92a71bf21a09/flink-connectors/flink-connector-twitter/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/twitter/TwitterSource.java) has been implemented.

> Gracefully Stopping Functions
>   Functions may additionally implement the {@link
>   org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.StoppableFunction} interface.
>   "Stopping" a function, in contrast to "canceling" means a graceful
>   exit that leaves the state and the emitted elements in a consistent
>   state

.